# Displaying assignments for each user in a day

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am building a time-sheet display of users having various assignments on a day (or given time-frame)

Right now I am achieving this by once selecting all users assigned for the day, looping over them and in each loop selecting all the assignments the users may have on the day.

The main select

```
SELECT u.id, u.name 
FROM users u, assignments a, events e
WHERE u.id = a.u_id AND a.e_id = e.id AND e.date = '{DATE}'
GROUP BY u.id
```

The select in each loop of the main select

```
SELECT e.title, e.date  
FROM assignments a LEFT JOIN events e ON e.id = a.e_id
WHERE a.u_id = {u.id_FROM_SELECT_ABOVE} AND e.date = '{DATE}'
```

Can this be achieved in a single better performing select? Sometimes the time-sheet may have hundreds of users per day with several assignments each while event & assignments tables of tens of thousands of records. I am doing this in PHP

Comment: Trust the optimizer, do it all in one select.

Comment: Well, thanks, that's what I was asking about :))

Answer (score 0):

Optimizer should handle this query fine:

```
SELECT e.title, e.date  
FROM assignments a LEFT JOIN events e ON e.id = a.e_id
WHERE a.u_id in (
  SELECT u.id
  FROM users u, assignments a, events e
  WHERE u.id = a.u_id 
    AND a.e_id = e.id 
    AND e.date = '{DATE}'
  GROUP BY u.id
)
  AND e.date = '{DATE}'
```